# Data types in Athena for a column with % sign

Tags: sql, csv, amazon-athena

I got a csv file that contains a column with a rate, so the % sign is included in the file. I wanna map a table on that file in Athena but I don't know how to treat that specific column. I've been using decimal(10,0) but it's not working.

Comment: Load the data into a string in a staging table.  Do subsequent processing in the database.

Comment: Can you update your question with  some sample records ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your table with that column typed as a string, then use for example `CAST(REPLACE(col, '%') AS double)/100` to remove the % sign and divide the numerical value by 100.

If you want to avoid having to do it in every query you can create a view that includes the operation and run your regular queries against that view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW the_rate_view AS
SELECT
  *,
  CAST(REPLACE(col, '%') AS double)/100 AS my_rate
FROM the_original_table
```

Now you can use `the_rate_view` the same way as `the_original_table`, but also use the `my_rate` column which is the percentages converted to rates.